# pytorch - use device inside 'with statement'

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

Is there a way of running `pytorch` inside the context of a specific (GPU) device (without having to specify the device for each new tensor, such as the `.to` option)?

Something like an equivalent of the `tensorflow` `with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):`..

It seems that the default device is the cpu (unless I'm doing it wrong):

```
with torch.cuda.device('0'):
   a = torch.zeros(1)
   print(a.device)

>>> cpu
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unfortunately in the current implementation the `with-device` statement doesn't work this way, it can just be used to switch between cuda devices.**

---

You still will have to use the `device` parameter to specify which device is used (or `.cuda()` to move the tensor to the specified GPU), with a terminology like this when:

```py
# allocates a tensor on GPU 1
a = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda)
```

So to access `cuda:1`:

```py
cuda = torch.device('cuda')

with torch.cuda.device(1):
    # allocates a tensor on GPU 1
    a = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda)
```

And to access `cuda:2`:

```py
cuda = torch.device('cuda')

with torch.cuda.device(2):
    # allocates a tensor on GPU 2
    a = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda)
```

However tensors without the `device` parameter will still be CPU tensors:

```py
cuda = torch.device('cuda')

with torch.cuda.device(1):
    # allocates a tensor on CPU
    a = torch.tensor([1., 2.])
```

**To sum it up:**

> No - unfortunately it is in the current implementation of the `with-device`
>   statement not possible to use in a way you described in your
>   question.

---

Here are some more examples from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html#device-agnostic-code):

```py
cuda = torch.device('cuda')     # Default CUDA device
cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
cuda2 = torch.device('cuda:2')  # GPU 2 (these are 0-indexed)

x = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda0)
# x.device is device(type='cuda', index=0)
y = torch.tensor([1., 2.]).cuda()
# y.device is device(type='cuda', index=0)

with torch.cuda.device(1):
    # allocates a tensor on GPU 1
    a = torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=cuda)

    # transfers a tensor from CPU to GPU 1
    b = torch.tensor([1., 2.]).cuda()
    # a.device and b.device are device(type='cuda', index=1)

    # You can also use ``Tensor.to`` to transfer a tensor:
    b2 = torch.tensor([1., 2.]).to(device=cuda)
    # b.device and b2.device are device(type='cuda', index=1)

    c = a + b
    # c.device is device(type='cuda', index=1)

    z = x + y
    # z.device is device(type='cuda', index=0)

    # even within a context, you can specify the device
    # (or give a GPU index to the .cuda call)
    d = torch.randn(2, device=cuda2)
    e = torch.randn(2).to(cuda2)
    f = torch.randn(2).cuda(cuda2)
    # d.device, e.device, and f.device are all device(type='cuda', index=2)
```

Comment: yes that's what I'm doing now. The question was if it was possible to make the "default" instantiation (like, if I don't specify `device` parameter) to be the gpu instead of cpu (the specific device, whether 0,1 or 2 is less important)

Comment: @nivniv As I said above - no unfortunately it doesn't work that, it only affects cuda devices, not cpu.

Answer (score 1):

**This update reflects the advancements in PyTorch as of 2023.**

Starting `pytorch==2.0.0` the `torch.device` can be used as context manager to point the default device for new tensors.

Source: [Pull Request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/91796), [Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/changing_default_device.html)

Here's an example to demonstrate this new functionality:

```
with torch.device('cuda'):
    mod = torch.nn.Linear(20, 30)
    print(mod.weight.device)   # Output: cuda:0
    print(mod(torch.randn(128, 20)).device)  # Output: cuda:0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).